# How to map Dictionary<enum1,enum2> with Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent

I was mapping a relation using something like the following

```
<map name="Foo" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
  <key column="FooId"/>
  <index column="FooType" type="Domain.Enum.FooType, Domain"/>
  <element column ="FooStatus" type="Domain.Enum.FooStatus, Domain"/>
</map>
```

The class is like this

```
namespace Domain {
    public class Enum {
        public enum FooType {
            Foo1,
            Foo2,
            ...
      Foo50}
       public enum FooStatus {
           NotNeeded,
           NeededFor1,
           NeededFor2,
      NeededFor3,
      NiceToHave}
    }
}
```

Can I do this using Fluent Nhibernate?
If not can I map a class mixing Fluent and XML?

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER From Fluent NHibernate Google group were I asked the same question

The short answer is no, you cannot do this with the fluent interface at the 
moment. My initial implementation of AsMap() was rather naive and does not 
support your scenario. I will raise it as an issue and get back to you once 
a fix is in place but in the meantime you should be able to work around it 
by mixing xml with fluent mappings. I know we have several users that are 
currently doing this. The exact steps would depend on how you have it set 
up.

Paul Batum

Comment: I believe this has been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Forget to add

```
namespace Domain 
{
public virtual IDictionary<FooType, FooStatus> MyFoo { set; get; }
}
```