# How do I map a dictionary using Fluent NHibernate automapping?

Tags: configuration, fluent-nhibernate, dictionary, automapping

I have an entity like so:

```
public class Land
{
    public virtual IDictionary<string, int> Damages { get; set; }
    // and other properties
}
```

Every time I try to use automapping with the following code:

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory)
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Land>))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I get the following error:

```
{"The type or method has 2 generic parameter(s), but 1 generic argument(s) were
provided. A generic argument must be provided for each generic parameter."}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Also, this is just a simple example. I have much more dictionaries than just this one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410716/fluentnhibernate-mapping-for-dictionary

Try AsMap()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is impossible with NHibernate.

Comment: Do you mean this to be impossible with Fluent NHibernate automapping, Fluent NHibernate as a whole (meaning with the fluent mappings as well), or NHibernate itself?

Comment: NHibernate itself. I do not know any ORM that could automap dictionary at present moment.

Comment: You're right, you have to manually map it. Using Fluent, it'd be `References(x => x.Dictionary).AsMap<int>("keyColumn").Element("valueColumn", c => c.Type<string>());`.

Answer (score 3):

Found some traces that this [isn't possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360976/fluent-code-for-mapping-an-idictionarysomeentity-int). Some traces, that [it's recently implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243464/how-to-map-dictionaryenum1-enum2-with-fluent-nhibernate/266607#266607).

Still investigating. :)

---

[This looks quite promising](http://hotrannam.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/mapping-simple-idictionary-with-fluent-nhibernate/) (didn't test yet).

So, in your case it should look like=>

```
public class LandMap : ClassMap<Land>
{
    public LandMap()
    {
        (...)

        HasMany(x => x.Damages)
            .WithTableName("Damages")
            .KeyColumnNames.Add("LandId")
            .Cascade.All()
            .AsMap<string>(
                index => index.WithColumn("DamageType").WithType<string>(),
                element => element.WithColumn("Amount").WithType<int>()
            );
    }
}
```

Keep in mind - it **should**. I didn't test it.

Comment: That's for fluent mapping. I'm looking for something that works for automapping because I have about 50 dictionaries across all my entities.

Comment: Ahhh... sorry. Somehow didn't notice `automapping`. I'll take a look. :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround that should in theory work with automapping:

```
public class DamagesDictionary : Dictionary<string, int>
{
}
```

Land.cs

```
public class Land
{
   public virtual DamagesDictionary Damages { get; set; }
   // and other properties
}
```

---

or a more generic approach...

```
public class StringKeyedDictionary<T> : Dictionary<string, T>
{
}
```

Land.cs

```
public class Land
{
   public virtual StringKeyedDictionary<int> Damages { get; set; }
   // and other properties
}
```

Comment: I think this is an underrated answer - simpler sometimes to make another POCO with 2 properties on it (Key, Value) and reference that if you can't be bothered to write the mappings (Lazy, yes.. Recommender, no... but...)